# Model Binding with Pagination TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination

I have the following `PageLinkTagHelper.cs` that generates pagination links for a list of items

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "page-model")]
    public class PageLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;

        public PageLinkTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory helperFactory)
        {
            urlHelperFactory = helperFactory;
        }

        [ViewContext]
        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        public PagingInfo PageModel { get; set; }

        public string PageAction { get; set; }

        public bool PageClassesEnabled { get; set; } = false;
        public string PageClass { get; set; }
        public string PageClassNormal { get; set; }
        public string PageClassSelected { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context,
                TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
            for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction,
                   new { listPage = i });
                if (PageClassesEnabled)
                {
                    tag.AddCssClass(PageClass);
                    tag.AddCssClass(i == PageModel.CurrentPage
                        ? PageClassSelected : PageClassNormal);
                }
                tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
                result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
            }
            output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
```

I am struggling to modify this to work with model binding. I would like to use it in the following method:

```
public IActionResult SearchResult(SearchResultViewModel viewModel, int listPage =1)
        {
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                List<Form> searchResult = GetSearchResult(viewModel.SearchTerms).ToList();
                var model = new SearchResultViewModel
                {
                    Forms = searchResult
                        .OrderBy(f => f.FormID)
                        .Skip((listPage - 1) * PageSize)
                        .Take(PageSize),
                    SearchTerms = new SearchTerms
                    {
                        //search criteria deleted for brevity
                    },
                    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                    {
                        CurrentPage = listPage,
                        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                        TotalItems = searchResult.Count()
                    }
                };

                return View("SearchResult", model);
            }
            return View("SearchForms");
        }
```

The link generated is `localhostXXXX/Form/SearchResult?listPage=#` where the correct list page is generated. However, the `SearchResultViewModel` passed to the controller upon clicking the link is null. This has the effect of returning all the items in the repository (since there are no search terms to filter on). How can I bind my `SearchResultViewModel.cs` object with this pagination?

My View is

```
@model SearchResultViewModel
@foreach (var form in Model.Forms)
{
    @Html.Partial("FormSummary", form)
}

<div page-model="@Model.PagingInfo" page-action="SearchResult" page-classes-enabled="true" page-class="btn" page-class-selected="btn-primary" class="btn-group pull-right m-1"></div>
```

Comment: you dont have to use @ for a tag helper `page-model="Model.PagingInfo"` should work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `SearchResultViewModel` to be null, you need to pass something like `localhostXXXX/Form/SearchResult?PagingInfo.CurrentPage=#`. In which case you are setting a property of `SearchResultViewModel`.

Comment: I've tried setting model properties with hidden input boxes both with `name` and `asp-for` TagHelpers but the model is still null

Comment: hope you added it inside a form and submitted the form"

Comment: The problem may be in the tag helper. It works fine if it's a `<button>` but not a `<div>`. Problem is, I can't get the button styled right